# What will happen if I don't response RTSP GET_PARAMETER command?

Tags: rtsp

I'm developing a RTSP Server and UDP works fine, but there's 1 issue when it's goes to TCP which is the VLC only can view streaming about 30 minutes, from the packet I see that I didn't response the RTSP GET_PARAMETER command, is this command matters and what will happen is I don't response this command?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7826), `GET_PARAMETER` is optional for servers and clients to implement.